# How can I prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin n}{n+1} = 1$

Tags: limits, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

How to prove $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1} = 1$ ?

The beginning:

Fix $\epsilon$ > 0. Is there an $N\in \mathbb{N},$ such that
$$n\ge N \implies\left|\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1 \right|<\epsilon?$$

$$\left|\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1 \right|<\epsilon \iff$$ 
$$\left|\frac{\sin(n)-1}{n+1}\right|<\epsilon \iff$$
$$\ldots$$

I got that $n > \frac{2}{\epsilon}-1$, is that right?

N=(max or min ?) {0, $\lfloor\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1\rfloor$}

I hope that the task is understandable.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: $\sin(n)$ is bounded, then ....

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What did you try?

Comment: "Proof" does not equal "prove".

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I removed the request for an epsilon delta proof that was requested after a lot of answers were already posted.

Answer (score 3):

Note that
$$\left|\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1\right|=\left|\frac{-1+\sin(n)}{n+1}\right|\leq \frac{1+|\sin(n)|}{n+1}.$$
Now recall that $\sin(n)\in [-1,1]$. 
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

First, devide the numerator and denominator by $n$

$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1} =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\sin(n)/n}{1+1/n}=1$$

and then use $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sin(n)}{n}=0$ as $|\sin(n)|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}=\dfrac{1+\frac{\sin(n)}{n}}{1+\frac{1}{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need to show that for $ \epsilon \gt 0$,  there is an $N_0(\epsilon)$ such that  for $n\gt N_0$:

$|\dfrac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1| \lt \epsilon.$

Let $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ given.

Choose: $N_0$ such that  $\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}   \lt N_0 .$

For $n \gt N_0:$

$\bigl| \dfrac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1} -1\bigr|$=

$|\dfrac{\sin(n) -1}{n+1}| \lt |\dfrac{2}{n}| \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

Start out by separating your numerator: $$\lim{\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}}=\lim{\frac{n}{n+1}}+\lim{\frac{\sin(n)}{n+1}}$$ The first term goes to one, and the second to zero, giving a final answer of one.