# Epsilon-Delta Proof $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1} = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

How To Construct a Epsilon-Delta proof $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1} = 1$ ?

The beginning:

Fix $\epsilon$ > 0. Is there an $N\in \mathbb{N},$ such that
$$n\ge N \implies\left|\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1 \right|<\epsilon?$$

$$\left|\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n+1}-1 \right|<\epsilon \iff$$ 
$$\left|\frac{\sin(n)-1}{n+1}\right|<\epsilon \iff$$
$$\ldots$$

I got that $n > \frac{2}{\epsilon}-1$, is that right?

N=(max or min ?) {0, $\lfloor\frac{2}{\epsilon}-1\rfloor$}

I hope that the task is understandable.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: So far so good.  Note that the numerator is bounded.

Comment: $|\sin n-1|\leq2$.

Comment: No `\displaystyle` in titles, please.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Use the triangular inequality for the numerator and the boundedness of $\sin(n)$ by $|\sin(n)|\leq 1$:

$$\biggl|\frac{\sin(n)-1}{n+1}\biggr|\leq \frac{|\sin(n)|+1}{|n+1|}\leq \frac{1+1}{|n+1|}=\frac{2}{n+1}$$

Comment: Minor addendum but we could even skip the triangle equality step and say $\left|\frac{\sin(n)-1}{\ldots}\right|=\frac{|\sin(n)-1|}{|\ldots|}\leq\frac{2}{|\ldots|}$ since we know that $-2\leq\sin(n)-1\leq0$. Great answer regardless :)

Comment: @Jam: You are right, but I would still prefer the triangular inequality because it makes it explicit what is implicitly hidden in $-2\leq \sin(n) -1 \leq 0$.

Comment: You could also use $1- \sin(n) =  2\sin^2(n/2 + \pi/4)$ to derive that inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Try these:
$|x-y| \leq |x| + |y|$ and $|\sin(x)|\leq1$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2442833/how-can-i-prove-that-lim-limits-n-to-infty-fracn-sin-nn1-1/2442899#2442899